# Fill textboxes in MS Word using LiveDocX API and php

Tags: php, ms-word, livedocx

I'm using livedocs api 2.1 and fill mergefields with code like this which works fine

```
$soap->SetFieldValues(array ('fieldValues' => assocArrayToArrayOfArrayOfString($fieldValues)));
```

But how can I fill texboxes (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/wo...010354856.aspx) using API? I can't mark them as MergeFields, right? What shall I do? And I cant replace textboxes with simple text, that's the rule.

Comment: By "marking them as MergeFields" do you mean "putting Mergefields in them"? If so, is anything actually stopping you from doing that? OK, Word itself may not deal with mergefields in textboxes in a very helpful way, but that doesn't mean that you can't do something sensible with them.

Comment: Yes, putting Mergefields in them. I tried this way before that post, and it doesn't wark